# Received the transaction id but the transaction never happened

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node, transaction, api, blockfrost

I used to work with [Blockfrost](https://blockfrost.io/) API to submit my transactions. A few days ago, I ran into this problem in which my transactions were submitted successfully (The API returned me the transaction id without any error) but the transactions were never actually processed (When I looked for transactions in the [Cardanoscan](https://cardanoscan.io/), nothing was found). I decided to submit my transactions on [another node](https://dandelion.link/), and it did work fine for a couple of days, and now I have the same issue. Does anyone know where the problem might be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The chain has been pretty congested since sundaeswap launched. It may take some time between transaction submission and inclusion into a block. If your TTL or --invalid-hereafter parameter is too short, the TX may be submitted to the mempool but be invalid by the time it is to be included in a block. Try setting the TTL to something like 10000+ and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks! Would set TTL something very very high cause any problem?

Comment: None that I can think of off the top :)

Comment: @Foad You could omit the TTL entirely